# Accept SSL cert for wrong domain

Tags: openssl

A site has recycled their SSL cert from another site which is causing me errors on the command line (wget, etc).
They have 2 certs on different parts of the site both issued by the same authority which I have added the root and intermediate CRT's for.

What additional steps may I take to allow my system (12.04) to accept this 2nd cert with the wrong domain?
Clarification: These are two different domains and TLD's, not a sub-domain mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

This is the case where the client uses the wrong certificate for the wrong domain. Now the client is not using a standard browser to make the connectivity but instead using a command line. In a browser environment  the error message the client would have received is “The Name of the Security Certificate Is Invalid or Does Not Match the Name of the Site”. This is the intended behavior and one of the 3 main verification process that all SSL certificates must pass for SSL connectivity to be made. Unfortunately the client can only use the certificate for the exact common name (FQDN) that is was requested for. Again that is expect behavior and the client must obtain a different certificate for the different FQDN that they need the certificate for.

Here is one solution that we provide to our clients: 
https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index?page=content&id=SO16685

Another recommendation is to buy a SAN certificate that supports different FQDNs for any potential services they need.

Jimmy Edge - [Symantec SSL](http://www.symantec.com/en/uk/ssl-certificates) employee